# Access external program data files from script in Python

Tags: python, windows, external

I have external data input that I use in my python scripts (in fact an excel file as a template). This external file is specific to the version of the script that I check in to SVN. So I suppose I should check in the external file as well?

How would you manage that the script finds the file (I use Windows)? A relative path to the current directory? Checking sys.path paths manually? Some parameter given to the script which specifies the root directory of relative path accesses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common idiom for finding data files is this:

```
my_dir = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
data_file_path = os.path.join(my_dir, data_filename)
```

So if your script lives in `/some/path/script.py`, and `data_filename` is `myfile`, this will correctly find `/some/path/myfile` when your script is executed.

---

This works on Windows as well as Linux

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you are right you should add your file to SVN if it is vital for your programm overall and is needed at runtime. I would use relative path and put said file inside the project folder.

For the second part of your question take a look at [diveintopython](http://www.diveintopython.net/functional_programming/finding_the_path.html) very good explanation on different ways to access the path of the script.

Comment: Thanks. How would I access the project root directory in windows?

Comment: I see. So you would access the path of the script and not use some windows variables :) I'll do that.